# How to get all C# types or namespaces that Roslyn couldn't find?

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm using Roslyn to parse a C# project. I have a [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.compilation?view=roslyn-dotnet) object that represents this project. However, this project might not have been compiled successfully; there may be several reasons for this, but I'm specifically interested in any references to a type or a namespace that couldn't be resolved. **How can I use my `Compilation` object to retrieve all unknown namespaces or types as [`IErrorTypeSymbol`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.ierrortypesymbol?view=roslyn-dotnet)s?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to loop over all `SyntaxTree`s and use the compilation's `SemanticModel` to identify error types.

Something like...

```cs
// assumes `comp` is a Compilation

// visit all syntax trees in the compilation
foreach(var tree in comp.SyntaxTrees)
{
    // get the semantic model for this tree
    var model = comp.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    
    // find everywhere in the AST that refers to a type
    var root = tree.GetRoot();
    var allTypeNames = root.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<TypeSyntax>();
    
    foreach(var typeName in allTypeNames)
    {
        // what does roslyn think the type _name_ actually refers to?
        var effectiveType = model.GetTypeInfo(typeName);
        if(effectiveType.Type != null && effectiveType.Type.TypeKind == TypeKind.Error)
        {
            // if it's an error type (ie. couldn't be resolved), cast and proceed
            var errorType = (IErrorTypeSymbol)effectiveType.Type;

            // do what you want here
        }
    }
}
```

Unknown namespaces require a bit more finessing after your crawl, since you can't really tell whether `Foo.Bar` is referring to "a type Bar in Foo" or "a namespace Foo.Bar" without metadata.  It's possible I'm forgetting some place where Roslyn will smuggle type-referring syntax nodes... but `TypeName` is what I recall.

Comment: That did it, thanks! This retrieves both unknown types and unknown namespaces; in my use case, as long as I can get information about both I don't need to make a distinction. I'm outputting diagnostics for humans, not for other programs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifierNameSyntax) which returns a SymbolInfo. SymbolInfo.Symbol is an ISymbol, so you can use ISymbol.ContainingNamespace to get the namespace an identifier belongs to.